# can't add user to a group

Tags: groups

I would like to add my usr `ron` to the `docker` group, so I did the following:

```
ron@regDesktopHome:~$ sudo usermod -a -G docker ron
ron@regDesktopHome:~$ groups
ron
```

Why does it only show group `ron` as the user obviously also is a member of `sudo`(+others)...?

**edit**

```
$ grep ron /etc/group
sudo:x:27:ron
dip:x:30:ron
crontab:x:102:
netdev:x:111:ron
vboxusers:x:124:ron
ron:x:1001:
incron:x:138:
wireshark:x:148:ron
docker:x:153:ron
```

Now something doesn't look right here: 
The following is after I opened a from `XTerm` instance on my desktop:

```
ron@regDesktopHome:~$ groups
ron
ron@regDesktopHome:~$ su ron
Password: 
ron@regDesktopHome:~$ groups
ron sudo dip netdev vboxusers wireshark docker
ron@regDesktopHome:~$
```

why would I first need to "relogin" as my own user in order to become a member of the groups, that doesn't seem to make sense, does it?

Comment: What does `grep ron /etc/group` show?

Comment: @ajgringo619 please see above edited OG. Thanks!

Comment: OK - at least your groups are still good. Try logging off, then back on.

Comment: `newgrp docker`  make the change on the fly.

Comment: @ajgringo619 yeps, i did a `su ron` and now `groups` shows me all of the above as expected! Great, Thanks!

Comment: `su $USER` solved my problem although I am `$USER`. Thanks